# NSDateFormatter returns nil while calling datefromstring method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to create a date object with the specified formatter but date formatter_datefromstring method returns nil. Please let me know with the clear documentation samples. The String am trying to parse is "2:00 AM PDT on September 24, 2017". Thanks in advance

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a Z 'on' MMMM d, yyyy"];
    NSLog(@"dateStr:==============> %@", dateStr);
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"Date:------------->%@", date);
    return date;
```

Comment: What is `dateStr`?

Comment: Provide the date string that you are trying to convert into NSDate.

Comment: Is your device/simulator set for English?

Comment: Yes it does..@rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong timezone specifier. `Z` is for timezones such as `-0800`. You need `z` for short timezone abbreviations like `PDT`.

Also, there is no reason to set the formatter's local to `currentLocale` and the timezone to `systemTimeZone` since those are the defaults. And the timezone of the formatter is irrelevant when the string you are parsing contains timezone information.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a z 'on' MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSLog(@"dateStr:==============> %@", dateStr);
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"Date:------------->%@", date);
return date;
```

However, since you are parsing a fixed format date string that is in English, you really should set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. This will ensure it handles the English month name no matter the user's locale.

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue. This lets people know your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your dateStr date format and your given format same or not. If both are not same format you will get nil object. Try dateStr format in given below example.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"10:23 am Z on September 30, 2017";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a Z 'on' MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSLog(@"dateStr:==============> %@", dateStr);
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"Date:------------->%@", date);
```

In console you will get 
2017-09-23 09:54:04.654597+0530 Date[4068:79926] dateStr:==============> 10:23 am Z on September 30, 2017
2017-09-23 09:54:04.657359+0530 Date[4068:79926] Date:------------->Sat Sep 30 15:53:00 2017

Comment: Please review the question. It includes a specific example of the string being parsed. Your answer is using a different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below locale the avoid returning nil value.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

Vote my code if it is usefull

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: i had a problem like the above., i fixed by adding locale., my problem is when i change to device date format to 12 hours to 24 hours my app crashes.